# Gridview bind to label from database and extra text

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am binding a label simply like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" Text='<%# Bind("Field")%>'></asp:Label>
```

But i want to add some text next to "Field", so the label reads "Field, more text" I am trying this, but it doesn't work.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" Text='<%# Bind("RoleID") + "more text"%>'></asp:Label>
```

I have also tried:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" Text='<%# String.Format(Bind("RoleID") + "more text"%>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this...

```
Text='<%# Eval("RoleID").ToString() + "more text"%>'>
```

Comment: when i do that i get this error, 'Bind' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `RowDatabound` event of `Grid View` Like

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" Text='<%#Bind("Field")%>'></asp:Label>
```

**Code:**

```
protected void GridView_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lblvalue = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label3"));

                // add text here
            }
        }
```

Or You may use

```
e.Row.Cells(3).Text += " more text.";
```

on `RowDataBound` event.Here `Cells(3)` is the cell index you have to use your's.

Hope you understand and it works for you.

Comment: I appreciate that but I didn't want to use code-behind this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
 Bind("field", "{0} more text")
```